# Unable to connect to server via RDP after a day or 2

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a test server HP Proliant DL380 G7 I use it for test purposes, i have set up rdp to be able to use the server without being there, I have a total of 5 users who use this with me.

Specifications:

OS: Windows server 2008 x86

5 Users in total

HP Proliant DL380 G7

(Let me know if this isn't sufficent)

I have not decided to reformat this as I don't want to redo the application I have installed for test purposes

When ever I try connecting to it after 1-2 days it is stuck in "Configuring remote session".
My server is fully updated with the latest updates the windows server 2008 gives, Can someone help me out?

Comment: There may be bugs connecting from newer win10/11 clients via RDP to 2008 because it's been unsupported for years. You can try restarting `TermService` or the server regularly, or resetting the RDS configurations. If you only see this when reconnecting to existing sessions, you could configure RDP to automatically log off disconnected sessions after a certain period of time

Comment: Restarting TermService would be inconvinient at times if I am unable to connect to it sometimes, is there any way I can automate this? Could you guide me on how I can configure those RDP Configurations?

Comment: You can use task scheduler to automate it like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309449/how-to-restart-a-windows-service-using-task-scheduler

Comment: Is there any other solution then this? as it would be easier to solve the problem once and for all.

Comment: It will take some blind digging - the symptoms are pretty vague, and can be caused by lots of stuff (out of resources/memory, antivirus or other installed software, corruption, etc) and most of them are 'fixed' by rebooting. You can check the system or TermService event logs for better error messages to research. However, in many cases it might take just as long to redo your application on a working server

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I had done as you have told me, the best option being formatting it worked smoothly for about 1-2 weeks before returning to the usual 1-2 days consecutive configuring state, I have looked at the event viewer and from that I have seen so many errors popping up if you could take a look and tell me what the  issue could be it would be helpfull most of the error is CAPi2
https://imgur.com/a/kfD1XbF